# Tabular Formatting w/ Python

Tags: python, tabular

I am trying to get the output of the following code:

```
for x in range(1,100):
   if x==2:
      print(x)
   else:
      for i in range (2,x):
        if x%i==0:
            break
        elif x%i!=0:
            if i==(x-1):
                print(x)
```

with an output as following:

```
 2   3   5   7  11  13  17  19  23  29
31  37  41  43  47  53  59  61  67  71
73  79  83  89  97
```

1. must be rows of only ten
2. single digits must stack on singles, tens on tens, etc.

Comment: print should handle "\t", and format code properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## '%4s' % prime

If you have a prime, you could use `'%4s' % prime` to right-align the prime in 4 characters (you might choose another width, or adapt it depending on your range) :

```
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41,
          43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]

width = 4
cell_format = '%'+str(width)+'s'
cells = 10

for i,p in enumerate(primes):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print
    print cell_format % p,
```

It outputs :

```
   2    3    5    7   11   13   17   19   23   29
  31   37   41   43   47   53   59   61   67   71
  73   79   83   89   97
```

## Your code :

### Python 2

```
count = 0
cells = 10
for x in range(1,100):
   if x==2:
      print('%4s' % x),
   else:
      for i in range (2,x):
        if x%i==0:
            break
        elif x%i!=0:
            if i==(x-1):
                count += 1
                if count % cells == 0:
                    print("")
                print('%4s' % x),
```

### Python 3

```
count = 0
cells = 10
for x in range(1, 100):
    if x == 2:
        print('%4s' % x, end='')
    else:
        for i in range(2, x):
            if x % i == 0:
                break
            elif x % i != 0:
                if i == (x - 1):
                    count += 1
                    if count % cells == 0:
                        print("")
                    print('%4s' % x, end='')
print("")
```

Comment: "Your Code:" is close but it isnt printing horizontally

Comment: It did, at least with python2.7

Comment: im using python 3.6

Comment: @yelyr: Updated

Comment: Great. One last question. if you set the range starting >2 than the first row seems to skip the tenth column. Can you explain?

Comment: @yelyr: Yes. Since you printed `2` separately, I put `count += 1` before the other prints. If you remove the `2`, put the `count += 1` after the prints

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `print(str(x) + "\t") to have tab spaced output. If you will get each value in new line, then use sys.stdout.write instead of print.

additionally this condition `elif x%i!=0` is not needed, just use else

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(1,100):
   if x==2:
      print(x, end="\t")
   else:
      for i in range (2,x):
        if x%i==0:
            break
        elif x%i!=0:
            if i==(x-1):
                print(x, end="\t")
```

This puts a tabulator behind each print. You can use end=" " to put a space behind the print. With this your loop will not print each result in a different line.